A problom about singularity in stein Complex Analysis chapter3

Suppose that $f$ is meromorphic in the extended plane.Then $f\left( \frac{1}{z} \right)$ has either a pole or a removable singularity at $0$.

According to this,$$\lim\limits_{|z|\rightarrow \infty}f(z)=C \tag{1}$$or$$\lim\limits_{|z|\rightarrow \infty}f(z)=\infty \tag{2}$$should hold($C$ is a constant).
Based on the defination of meromorphic,$f$ is either holomorphic at infinity or has a pole at infinity,how can we infer (1) or (2) from this?
There's an another small question.  In the defination of meromorphic,we can infer that $f$ is holomorphic at infinity(There's $N>0$ such that $\forall |z|>N$,$f$ is holomorphic at $z$ ) from has a pole at infinity,so why "is holomorphic or has a pole at infinity" ?

If $f(\frac 1  z)$ has an essential singularity at $0$  then $f( z)$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$, which is  not allowed.

let $f(z)=e^{z}$,then $f\left( \frac{1}{z} \right)=e^{ \frac{1}{z}}$ has an essential singularity at $0$,but $f(z)$ is holomorphic at infinity,it does not contradict the definition of meromorphic in the extended complex plane". What's wrong?

$e^{z}$ is not holomorphic at $\infty$.
